# Vector size mismatch in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I have been trying to write down a code for an LTI system where the response is calculated from an input `x(t)` and impulse `h(t)` response.

For the part of the code below:

```
y = conv(x,h).*steps;
ty = 0:steps:7;
plot(ty,y);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Error using `plot`
> Vectors must be the same length.

I'm using `ty = 0:steps:7;` as `h(t)` is defined as `exp(-t/2).*((t>=2)-(t>=7))` (since it extends upto `t=7`).

What does actually decide `ty`?

Comment: Does this mean `h(t)` exists only between `t=2` and `t=7`?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convolution Using Anonymous Functions

One way to do this process is to use anonymous functions/functions handles which are indicated by the `@()` that holds the input parameters in this case time, `t`. To create truncated signals conditional statements on `t` can be implemented. To have a signal ranging from `t=2` to `t=7` seconds truncation can be done by element-wise multiplying by `((t>=2) & (t<=7))`. The `t` vector used to plot the final result must have a time range that is the sum of the lengths of time of the signals used in the convolution process. I believe `ty` is the time vector to plot the output against. In this case you must ensure `ty` has the same length as the output `y`.

**Length of Results = Length of System Response + Length of Input Signal**

---

In the case below: 
x(t) → length = 1s
h(t) → length = 5s (2s to 7s) 
y(t) → length = 1s + 5s = 6s (2s to 8s)

[image: Convolution Results]

```
Step_Size = 0.1;
Start_Time = 0; End_Time = 7;
t = Start_Time: Step_Size: End_Time;

%Input into system x(t)%
x = @(t) 1.0.*(t >= 0 & t <= 1);
subplot(3,1,2); fplot(x);
title('x(t): Input into system');
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([0 1.1]);

%System impulse response h(t)%
h = @(t) exp(-t/2).*((t>=2) & (t<=7));
subplot(3,1,1); fplot(h);
title('h(t): System impulse response');
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
xlim([0 10]);

y = conv(x(t),h(t)).*Step_Size;
t = linspace(0,2*max(t),length(y));
subplot(3,1,3); plot(t,y);
title('y(t): Output/System Response');
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
```

Comment: Now I get it! The length(y) helps to match the vector length for the plot function, if I'm not mistaking right? I was having some confusion in that part. Thanks for the answer